# Tricky limits problem

Tags: limits

Find the limit of

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left[1 + \left(\frac{\log \cos x}{\log \cos(x/2)}\right)^2 \right]^2$$

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: I've edited your question with MathJax, please use mathjax in the future. Note that $\log_b a=\frac{\log a}{\log b}$

Comment: I have a doubt that the limit is even well-defined, since there are infinitely many $x$ such that $\cos x<0$ or $\cos(x/2)<0$.

Comment: Sorry the limit is to zero

Comment: The answers 289

Comment: I guess x is an element of $]-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}[$, in which case the cos is positive and x can ->0 without pb

Comment: As shown in comments and answer, just do it slowly looking at the pieces. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left[1 + \left(\frac{\log \cos x}{\log \cos(x/2)}\right)^2 \right]^2$$
$$\left[1+\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\log \cos x}{\log \cos(x/2)}\right)^2 \right]^2$$
$$\left[1+\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log \cos x}{\log \cos(x/2)}\right)^2 \right]^2$$
Apply L'Hopital
$$\left[1+\left(2\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}{\tan(x/2)}\right)^2 \right]^2$$
Apply L'Hopital
$$\left[1+\left(4\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sec^2 x}{\sec^2(x/2)}\right)^2 \right]^2$$
$$\left[1+\left(4\cdot\frac{\sec^20}{\sec^20}\right)^2 \right]^2$$
$$\left[1+\left(4\cdot\frac{1}{1}\right)^2 \right]^2=289$$

Comment: How can you bring the limit inside the exprssion?

Comment: @user34304 $$\lim_{x\to a} f(g(x))=f\left(\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\right)$$ if $f(x)$ is continuous.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** use the fact that
$$
\log x \sim_{x\to 1} x-1\\
\cos u =_{u\to 0} 1 - \frac{u^2}2 + o(u^2)
$$

---

then you get
$$
\log \cos x \sim-\frac{x^2}2\\
\log \cos \frac x2 \sim-\frac{x^2}8\\
\frac{\log \cos x}{\log \cos \frac x2} \to 4
$$

so the final limit is
$$
(1 + 4^2)^2 = 17^2 = 289
$$

Answer (score 0):

From the Taylor formula $\log(\cos x)$ behaves as $x^2/2$ near 0, hence the limit is $(1+4^2)^2=17^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$t=\cos(x/2)\to 1$

$\frac{\log \cos x}{\log \cos(x/2)}=\frac{\log 2\cos^2 (\frac{x}{2})-1}{\log \cos(x/2)}=\frac{\log 2t^2-1}{\log t}$

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log \cos x}{\log \cos(x/2)}=\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{\log (2t^2-1)}{\log t}=4$ by L'Hospital's rule.

Then use composite rule of limit.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

As $x \to 0$, $$\ln \cos x \sim \cos x-1 \sim -\frac{x^2}{2}$$